# Creating a DataFrame in Pandas using logical and operator

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas Datarame with some columns and I first wanted to print only those rows whose values in a particular column is less than a certain value. So I did:

```
df[df.marks < 4.5]
```

It successfully created the dataframe, now I want to add only those columns whose values are in a certain range, so I tried this:

```
df[(df.marks < 4.5 and df.marks > 4)]
```

but it's giving me an error:

```
712         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "    
713                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 714                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
715 
716     __bool__ = __nonzero__    
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do I resolve this? And initially I also thought that it would iterate through all the rows and check the truth value and then add the row in the dataframe, but it seems like this isn't the case, if so how does it add the row in the dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
df[(df.marks < 4.5) & (df.marks > 4)]
```

Slightly more generally, array logical operations are combined using parentheses around the individual conditions:

```
(a < b) & (c > d)
```

Similar for OR-combinations, or more than 2 conditions.

This is how it's set up in NumPy, with boolean operators on arrays, and Pandas has copied that behaviour.

Comment: @Evert is there a reason '&' works and 'and' doesn't?

Comment: @ash This is a design choice on NumPy's side. In plain Python, `and` can work on lists: `[1, 2, 3] and []` evaluates to `False`. With NumPy arrays, this won't work properly (you'll get a warning). To avoid confusion, NumPy picked the bitwise AND operator, `&`.

Comment: @ash [continued] The bitwise operator normally works on the single bits of its inputs; the NumPy array equivalent is that it works on the individual array elements of its input. The closest equivalent they could get. I think there's also an issue with overriding `and`, but you'll have to search for that (and details of these comments), as the full information is too large to be contained in this margin^H^H^H^H^H^Hcomment.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into that problem before. not 100% on cause but dataframe object does not like multiple conditions together.

```
  df[(df.marks < 4.5 and df.marks > 4)] -> will fail
```

Doing something like this usually will solve the problem.

```
  df[(df.marks < 4.5)] [(df.marks > 4)]
```

That project is not at the top of my head right now, but i think quoting them separately works too.

Comment: Hmmm, `dataframe object does not like multiple conditions together` - can you specify?

Comment: Yes, now I understand. You are use wrong syntax, Evert in comment s explain why `&` is necessary.

Comment: @evert provided the best answer. but see example above. conditions must be parenteszed

Comment: the part that took a while for me was why (df.marks < 4.5 & df.marks > 4) doesn't work also. good explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Evert's solution` is nice.

I add another 2 possible solutions:

... with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'marks':[4.2,4,4.4,3,4.5]})
print (df)
   marks
0    4.2
1    4.0
2    4.4
3    3.0
4    4.5

df = df[df.marks.between(4,4.5, inclusive=False)]
print (df)
   marks
0    4.2
2    4.4
```

... with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query("marks < 4.5 & marks > 4")
print (df)
   marks
0    4.2
2    4.4
```